# Apache2 rewrite working selectively

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following 2 *identical* lines in my .htaccess file

```
RewriteRule ^admin(.*)$ http://admin.abc.com/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^portal(.*)$ http://portal.abc.com/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

abc.com/portal - redirects nicely to portal.abc.com .

However - abc.com/admin - redirects to admin.abc.com/**admin** .

**Note:**
The root directory has a WordPress installation. IN order to cancel the redirection of *admin* to *wp-admin*, I added the following line to the theme's function.php:

```
remove_action( 'template_redirect', 'wp_redirect_admin_locations', 1000 );
```

Is that the issue?

(The quoted 2 *RewriteRules* are the first 2 lines in the .htaccess, right after "*RewriteEngine On*")

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those rules can't be doing that. I think you need to clear your browser cache and then you will find it works as you expect. You have some previous test result cached in your browser.